# Filter messages from FB archive using bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a little problem. I need to filter a really messy .htm file. It has got no newlines, its just a really long string of mess.

[image]

Basically I got a message archive from facebook. I need to filter messages just from a specific person so I can work with it later. The file is full of special characters and it's a little complicated for me to work with.

Every message looks like this.

```
<span class="user">User Name</span><span class="meta">Date and sh*t</span></div></div><p>MESSAGE I NEED</p>
```

The only thing I need is a message from a specific person and output it to a txt file.

I appreciate every help.

Thank you

Comment: Are you opposed to a solution using perl?

Comment: So the desired output is only `MESSAGE I NEED`?

Answer (score 2):

`grep` loves these things:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=<p>)[^<]*' file
MESSAGE I NEED
```

It starts catching the string from `<p>` and continues until a new `<` is found.

---

In case you want to fetch data from a specific user given in the `<span class="user">User Name</span>` block, then you can for example do:

```
$ user="User Name"
$ grep "<span class=\"user\">$user</span>" file | grep -Po '(?<=<p>)[^<]*'
MESSAGE I NEED
```

or hardcoding the name:

```
$ grep '<span class="user">User Name</span>' file | grep -Po '(?<=<p>)[^<]*'
MESSAGE I NEED
```

Comment: yup! +1 I have typed same actually...then you make me click "cancel"... ^_^

Comment: Haha I was one coffee ahead :) Nice to read I came out with the same solution you were thinking about. `grep` look "arounds" rules!

Comment: I never thought `grep` could do it so easily. +1

Comment: This is great +1. But it returns every message from every person from the archive. This is like a full fb message archive with all the people I have texted with. I need to filter messages from only 1 person.

Comment: Please @SaKer update your question to reflect that, giving some more input and desired output.

Comment: (funny I got 3 messages saying +1 and in fact I got +2 in total :D)

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk` command,

```
$ awk -v FS='(<p>|</p>)' '{print $2}' file
MESSAGE I NEED
```

I think you need something like this,

```
$ cat file
<span class="user">Bar</span><span class="meta">Date and sh*t</span></div></div><p>MESSAGE I NEED</p>
<span class="user">Foo</span><span class="meta">Date and sh*t</span></div></div><p>FOO starts with the letter F</p>

$ awk -v FS='(<p>|</p>)' '/Bar/{print $2}' file
MESSAGE I NEED
```

Comment: Or even `awk -v FS='(<p>|</p>|<span[^>]*>|</span>)' '$2=="User Name" {print $6}' file`, but it is not that clear.

Comment: The OP said he has no newlines in his input file so that won't work. Also -v FS='(<p>|</p>)' can be written as just -F'</?p>' and as written you'd get false matches if Bar could appear as a substring of a name or anywhere on the line other than the user name area.

Answer (score 0):

Some like this?

```
awk '/Name/ {gsub(/<[^>]*>/, " ");$1=$1}1' file
User Name Date and sh*t MESSAGE I NEED
```

Change name to what you need, and this removes the tags.

Answer (score 0):

And the `sed` version:

```
$ sed -n 's/^.*<p>\([^<]*\)<.*$/\1/p' file
MESSAGE I NEED
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have newlines in your file so to break this down into per-user records we need to identify something else as the record separator. It looks like `</p>` is the obvious choice. Now we need to break each record down into fields so lets separate them with every `<...>` pair. Now given a sample input file containing 2 records:

```
$ cat file
<span class="user">Jim Bob</span><span class="meta">Date and sh*t</span></div></div><p>MESSAGE I NEED</p><span class="user">Bobby Joe</span><span class="meta">Date and sh*t</span></div></div><p>MESSAGE I DONT NEED</p>
```

We can output the fields (record number, field number, field contents):

```
$ awk -v RS='</p>' -F'<[^>]+>' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print NR, i, $i}' file
1 1
1 2 Jim Bob
1 3
1 4 Date and sh*t
1 5
1 6
1 7
1 8 MESSAGE I NEED
2 1
2 2 Bobby Joe
2 3
2 4 Date and sh*t
2 5
2 6
2 7
2 8 MESSAGE I DONT NEED
3 1
```

and see that the user name is the 2nd field in each record and the message is the 8th.

Given that, it's easy to just test/print whichever field(s) you want:

```
$ awk -v RS='</p>' -F'<[^>]+>' -v user="Jim Bob" '$2==user{print $8}' file
MESSAGE I NEED
```

Note that the above uses GNU awk for multi-char RS. For other awks the simplest approach is to convert all `</p>` strings to a control char before calling the script and then using that control char as the RS.